How to Extract Only Relevant Entities from Product Titles Using Google Cloud NLP API in Python?
I'm using the Google Cloud Natural Language API in Python to extract brand names and product types from e-commerce product titles. My goal is to filter out unnecessary details like specifications (e.g., CPU type, color, memory size) and only retain key information such as the brand name and the main product name.
Problem
I've written a script that preprocesses product titles and then uses the Google NLP API to extract entities. I'm trying to filter the entities based on their types (e.g., ORGANIZATION for brand names and CONSUMER_GOOD for product types) and salience. I want to avoid using a manual ignore_terms list and rely on entity type and salience to filter out irrelevant details.
My Code
Here's a simplified version of my code:
python
import os
import re
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import language_v1

# Load credentials from the JSON file
key_path = os.path.join('config', 'steam-insight-433515-f9-37e61ba35f98.json')
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path)

def preprocess_title(title):
    # Remove common punctuation marks
    title = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', title)
    title = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', title).strip()
    return title

def extract_entities(text):
    client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
    document = language_v1.Document(content=text, type_=language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
    response = client.analyze_entities(document=document)
    
    entities = []
    for entity in response.entities:
        entity_info = {
            'name': entity.name,
            'type': language_v1.Entity.Type(entity.type_).name,
            'salience': entity.salience,
            'metadata': entity.metadata
        }
        entities.append(entity_info)
    
    return entities

def construct_simplified_title(entities, original_title, brand_name=None, max_words=5):
    keywords = []
    if brand_name and brand_name.strip().lower() != 'generic':
        keywords.append(brand_name.strip())
    
    relevant_entities = []
    
    for entity in entities:
        entity_type = entity['type']
        entity_name = entity['name']
        salience = entity['salience']
        
        # Consider only ORGANIZATION (brand) and CONSUMER_GOOD (product name)
        if entity_type in ['ORGANIZATION', 'CONSUMER_GOOD']:
            relevant_entities.append((entity_name, entity_type, salience))
    
    # Sort entities by salience score in descending order
    relevant_entities.sort(key=lambda x: x[2], reverse=True)
    
    for entity_name, _, _ in relevant_entities:
        if entity_name.lower() not in [k.lower() for k in keywords]:
            keywords.append(entity_name)
        if len(keywords) >= max_words:
            break
    
    return ' '.join(keywords[:max_words])

# Example usage:
test_title_1 = "Apple 2024 MacBook Air (13-inch, Apple M3 chip with 8-core CPU and 10-core GPU, 16GB Unified Memory, 512GB) - Space Gray"
test_brand_1 = "Apple"
preprocessed_title_1 = preprocess_title(test_title_1)
entities_1 = extract_entities(preprocessed_title_1)
print(f"Entities Extracted: {entities_1}")
simplified_title_1 = construct_simplified_title(entities_1, preprocessed_title_1, brand_name=test_brand_1)
print(f"Simplified Title 1: {simplified_title_1}")

ven after attempting to filter by entity types and salience, my output still includes unwanted details:
Simplified Title 1: Apple 8-core CPU MacBook Air
I want the output to look like this: Simplified Title 1: Apple MacBook Air M3
What I’ve Tried
•   Filtering entities by type using ORGANIZATION and CONSUMER_GOOD.
•   Sorting entities by salience to prioritize more relevant entities.
•   Limiting the output to a set number of words.

